# Multiple join with Lambda Expression

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, inner-join

I have three tables.

```
*Contract*
ContractID(PK)
AgentID(FK)
CustomerID(FK)
Status

*Agent*
AgentID
Name

*Customer*
CustomerID
Name
```

I need to write a query to select all Contracts where Agent's name contains 'abc' and Customer's name contains 'xyz'.

My Linq query is:

```
from c in ctx.Contracts
from a in ctx.Agents
from cu in ctx.Customers
where c.CustomerID == cu.CustomerID && c.AgentID == a.AgentID && 
a.Name.Contains("abc") && cu.Name.Contains("xyz")
select c
```

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT 
[Filter1].[ContractID] AS [ContractID], 
[Filter1].[AgentID1] AS [AgentID], 
[Filter1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Filter1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID] 
FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ContractID] AS [ContractID], 
        [Extent1].[AgentID] AS [AgentID1], 
        [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
        [Extent1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID] 
        FROM  [dbo].[Contract] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Agent] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AgentID] = 
        [Extent2].[AgentID]
        WHERE [Extent2].[FirstName] LIKE N'%abc%' ) AS [Filter1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent3] ON [Filter1].[CustomerID] =
        [Extent3].[CustomerID]
        WHERE [Extent3].[FirstName] LIKE N'%xyz%'
```

I am struggling to write it in Lambda Expression. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And also how do I write the same query with 'OR'.

```
from c in ctx.Contracts
from a in ctx.Agents
from cu in ctx.Customers
where c.CustomerID == cu.CustomerID && c.AgentID == a.AgentID && 
a.Name.Contains("abc") || cu.Name.Contains("xyz")
select c
```

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent lambda expression of your `AND` version of query should look like this..

```
var result = ctx.Contracts.Join(ctx.Agents.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("abc")), 
                                c => c.AgentID, 
                                a => a.AgentID, 
                                (c, a) => c)                  
                            .Join(ctx.Customers.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("xyz")),
                                  c => c.CustomerID, 
                                 cu => cu.CustomerID, 
                               (c, cu) => c).ToList();
```

This is your `OR` version

```
var orResult = ctx.Contracts.Join(ctx.Agents,
            c => c.AgentID,
            a => a.AgentID,
            (c, a) => new {dContract = c, agetnName = a.Name})
            .Join(ctx.Customers,
                c => c.dContract.CustomerID,
                cu => cu.CustomerID,
                (c, cu) => new {ducontract = c, customerName = cu.Name})
        .Where(x => x.ducontract.agetnName.Contains("abc") || x.customerName.Contains("xyz"))
        .Select(y => y.ducontract.dContract).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting desired output. However the SQL is slightly different. Will both SQL produce the same result in all situations? SELECT [Extent1].[ContractID] AS [ContractID], [Extent1].[AgentID] AS [AgentID], [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], [Extent1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID] FROM [dbo].[Contract] AS [Extent1] INNER JOIN [dbo].[Agent] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[AgentID] = [Extent2].[AgentID] INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[CustomerID] = [Extent3].[CustomerID] WHERE ([Extent2].[Name] LIKE N'%abc%') AND ([Extent3].[Name] LIKE N'%xyz%').

Comment: When using 'OR', if the AgentID or CustomerID is null in Contract row, what is the best way to return those rows as well.

Comment: Yes, they do. SQL you posted in above comment is more valid. In the query you posted in the question, the results sets are joined as opposed to directly joining the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use join:

```
from c in ctx.Contracts
join a in ctx.Agents on c.AgentID equals a.AgentID
join cu in ctx.Customers on c.CustomerID equals cu.CustomerID
where a.Name.Contains("abc") && cu.Name.Contains("xyz")
select c;
```

RE:

> And also how do I write the same query with 'OR'.
>
> from c in ctx.Contracts from a in ctx.Agents from cu in ctx.Customers
>   where c.CustomerID == cu.CustomerID && c.AgentID == a.AgentID && 
>   a.Name.Contains("abc") || cu.Name.Contains("xyz") select c

The above doesn't work as && operator is more sticky than ||. To write the OR expression correctly use this:

```
from c in ctx.Contracts
from a in ctx.Agents
from cu in ctx.Customers
where 
    c.CustomerID == cu.CustomerID && c.AgentID == a.AgentID
    && ( a.Name.Contains("abc") || cu.Name.Contains("xyz") ) 
select c
```

Your original query condition, the one without parenthesis..

```
where c.CustomerID == cu.CustomerID && c.AgentID == a.AgentID && 
   a.Name.Contains("abc") || cu.Name.Contains("xyz")
```

..is evaluated as following. && is more sticky than ||

```
where 
    (
        c.CustomerID == cu.CustomerID 
        && c.AgentID == a.AgentID 
        && a.Name.Contains("abc")
    ) 
    || cu.Name.Contains("xyz")
```

Finally, this is what you want:

```
from c in ctx.Contracts
join a in ctx.Agents on c.AgentID equals a.AgentID
join cu in ctx.Customers on c.CustomerID equals cu.CustomerID
where a.Name.Contains("abc") || cu.Name.Contains("xyz")
select c;
```

By the way, why use lambda if you can use Linq? Or you can mix Linq and lambda. Using only lambda, makes the query hard to read: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2014/03/highfalutin-code-1.html

Comment: Thanks. I am also familiar with Linq. However I am using Expression Tree to dynamically build Where clause and the only way, I found, to use dynamic where clause, is to write Lambda Expression.